# Eclipse EE can't expand folder called 'services'

Tags: angularjs, eclipse, ibm-mobilefirst

I am developing a mobile application using IBM Mobile First using AngularJS in Eclipse EE. I have a basic file structure containing folders 'controllers', 'directives', 'filters' and 'services'. The problem is with Eclipse: In the Project explorer I can't seem to expand the 'services' folder. I can see the content of the folder in Windows Explorer as well as Sublime Text File three. When I rename the folder to something else I can however expand it in Eclipse.

What is the cause? Is there a solution to this problem or is it just something I have to live with? Any suggestions on alternative names then? I have to use Eclipse due to policies at my workplace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is special treatment by some Eclipse versions for folders named "services". By default, at least in some views such folders are hidden.

You can modify the view settings to turn off this very annoying behaviour. Bring up the view menu by clicking the little triangular icon, top right

[image]

select Customize view and in the content tab unselect Services Navigator Content.

[image]

Your services folder will now be visible.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there was once such an issue in MobileFirst - so I suggest one of two things:

1. Download the latest Studio update from IBM Fix Central, or the one from the Eclipse Marketplace.
2. Use a different folder name.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue.
There is a folder named 'services' created by MobileFirst by default(It is present after the 'server' folder).
So rename your 'services' folder to just 'service'. This is what I did.